# Run Winform Usercontrol in Thread or Process

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I want to run parts of my winform usercontrol (which are also usercontrols) as threads or even as new processes. But they still should be in the main winform. Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Please elaborate.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Because the main UI acts as a plugin for an external programm and will be blocked if the external programm is calculating and therefore also blocked.

Comment: Why not simply execute the program in a background thread?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov this is what I'm doing right now but the UI gets blocked because the parent program is also blocked (due to calculations)

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 2):

No. `UserControl`, and all other UI elements should be created on the main (UI) STA thread. Period. Cross-thread operations are not allowed.

You can take other parts of the control to another thread, but not as long as UI elements are involved (or you should use [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) when accessing them).

For parallel processing you have some nice features in .NET including the [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx), including [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx).

So for some calculations, you could do:

```
Task.Run( () => SomeHeavyMethod(1, 2, 3) );
```

But inside, you can't use UI elements, without using `Invoke`.

Comment: Should or cannot? - So this means all the UI elements will be in the same thread?

Comment: Definitely can't. All UI elements are in the same thread. Period.

Comment: Is it also not possible to start parts of the UI in another process and host them?

Comment: @martybourque WinForms controls are *not* threadsafe. It means cross-thread operations are potential issues. Of course, you can work with control in single thread. But what the point to have invisible control on thread which is not main thread, if application uses only main thread to interact with user and display data. You should do some calculations and other business logic on background threads, and then use controls on main thread to display results of those calculations

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: Thanks. I missed the keyword 'cross-thread operation'. Added it to the answer.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy it is a plugin and asks parent program for some heavy calc methods -> parent program blocks/freezes and so does my plugin UI -> therefore i wantet my plugin UI be in a different thread or process..

Comment: @martybourque: Do the heavy calculation in a separate thread. Not the UI operations.

Comment: And in worst case it would also be possible to start an external programm (with my UI) and place it inside the window where it's needed?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I cannot influence the heavy calculation because it's done ine the parent window... (I use backgroundworker, but that doesn't help anything -> if parent window freezes my window freezes too)

Comment: Then nothing of all this is going to help. If the main program is the issue and you can't influence it, you are stuck.

Comment: @martybourque: I don't get that part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to start a WinForm as standalone-process and then host it in your own window using the user32.dll - just like described here:

[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9123/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WinForm-project)